# Vertical scroll not working at the size of the screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve a scroll of users inside a flexbox menu.
I've realized something strange when I'm setting to my nav a height of px's(like 100px for instance) it'll work just fine, but when I'm setting a 100% height, it'll create a global scroll if there's not enough space, and my menu won't fit the size of the screen.
I've created two code-pens about the issue:

100% height for nav(scroll's not working)-

https://codepen.io/Shalev1104/pen/oNGYGgX

height with px(working scroll)-

https://codepen.io/Shalev1104/pen/KKXNXdB

*the only difference between them is the height property inside my `<nav>`.

In case you didn't understand, I need a vertical menu of 100% of the screen that has a vertical scroll inside of all the available spaces.

Glad for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentages are relative measurements (as in 100% of ...what?).
Make sure every parent element above the nav also has a height defined.

For example, if your site is structured like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav">...</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the following CSS will likely sort your problem:

```
html, body, ul.nav { height: 100%; }
```

---

Edit:
Here's an updated and cleaned version (both HTML and CSS):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav sidebar">
      <li class="nav-item sidebar-top">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Chat" />
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Search</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item sidebar-middle">
        <nav>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
          <li>d</li>
        </nav>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item sidebar-bottom">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3">
          <div>
            <img src="https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg" class="rounded-circle" width="50" height="50" alt="profile" />
            <span class="ms-2">User 1</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn bi-box-arrow-left">&nbsp;Disconnect</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <main>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>content on the page....</p>
      <p>Test</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%:
  background-color: red;
}
main {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.sidebar {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0; padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.sidebar-top {
  margin: 0; padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}
.sidebar-middle {
  margin: 0; padding: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sidebar-middle nav {
}
.sidebar-middle nav > li {
}
.sidebar-bottom {
  margin: 0; padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: same as you, I also think that setting the height 100% is stupid because I already have flex-grow which handles the height for me. your solution has just changed the scroll's position which is a good thing, but it expands on all the vertical nav(the outer nav) and it should be at the size of the inner nav. one more thing, my menu height is not as the size of the screen's height.

Comment: No i didn't mean 100% is stupid. i ment that, you have to let the browser know what you mean by 100%, because -unless- the ancestors have a height defined (be it pixels, be it 100%, same thing), `height: 100%` is meaningless.

Comment: Ok, so how could this be done?

Comment: If you post a bigger example on Codepen, (the entire <body> ... </body> of your page), then i can explain it more specifically; with the current example i cannot tell if there are other ancestors besides the ones ones in the snippet and presumably a <body> and <html> high up on the chain.

Comment: Can you edit the code?

Comment: I'd need to see what other html is above your `<ul class="nav.....`, or is that only the <body> element ?

Comment: There’s nothing above it, I didn’t defined an body and html element. I’ve created it just for demonstration.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you prefer to mainly use the bootstrap classes or mainly CSS style ? because you have both mixed at the moment and many conflict with eachother

Comment: I don’t mind, just want to solve this at any way given the code.

Comment: I've added the html/css to the answer above. I think this one works the way you want.

Comment: Great, Just as I was looking for, thank you so much!